# Find the equation y = y(x) from the intersection of two surfaces z = z(x,y)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, surface, nonlinear-functions

Given the equation `z = z(x,y)` of 2 surfaces `I` and `II`:

```
z_I(x, y) = a0 + a1*y + a2*x + a3*y**2 + a4*x**2  + a5*x*y
z_II(x, y) = a0_s2 + a1_s2*y + a2_s2*x + a3_s2*y**2 + a4_s2*x**2  + a5_s2*x*y
```

[image]

The parameters are given in the code (below).

The intersection of both surfaces is satisfied when:

```
z_I(x, y) = z_II(x, y)
```

How could I find the equation `y=y(x)` for this intersection?

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# parameters:
a0 =  -941.487789748
a1 =  0.014688246093
a2 =  -2.53546607894e-05
a3 =  -9.6435353414e-05
a4 =  -2.47408356408e-08
a5 =  3.77057147803e-07

a0_s2 =  -941.483110904
a1_s2 =  0.01381970471
a2_s2 =  -2.63051565187e-05
a3_s2 =  -5.5529184524e-05
a4_s2 =  -2.46707082089e-08
a5_s2 =  3.50929634874e-07


print """ 

The equations are the following:

z_I  (x, y) = a0 + a1*y + a2*x + a3*y**2 + a4*x**2  + a5*x*y
z_II (x, y) = a0_s2 + a1_s2*y + a2_s2*x + a3_s2*y**2 + a4_s2*x**2  + a5_s2*x*y

"""
print('z_I  (x, y) = ({a0}) + ({a1})*y + ({a2})*x  ({a3})*y**2  ({a4})*x**2  + ({a5})*x*y'.format(a0 = a0, a1 = a1, a2 = a2, a3 = a3, a4 = a4, a5 = a5))

print """
"""
print('z_II  (x, y) = ({a0_s2}) + ({a1_s2})*y + ({a2_s2})*x  ({a3_s2})*y**2  ({a4_s2})*x**2  + ({a5_s2})*x*y'.format(a0_s2 = a0_s2, a1_s2 = a1_s2, a2_s2 = a2_s2, a3_s2 = a3_s2, a4_s2 = a4_s2, a5_s2 = a5_s2))

print """
"""

print """
The intersection of both surfaces is satisfied when:

z_I(x, y) = z_II(x, y)

In other words, I am looking for the expression of the function y=y(x)

"""

##### For plotting:
x_mesh = np.linspace(10.0000000000000, 2000.0000000000000, 200)
x_mesh_2 = np.linspace(10.0000000000000, 2000.0000000000000, 200)
print x_mesh[0]
print x_mesh[-1]
y_mesh = np.linspace(-4.4121040129800, 10.8555489379000, 200)
y_mesh_2 = np.linspace(8.0622039627300, 17.6458151433000, 200)
print y_mesh[0]
print y_mesh[-1]

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x_mesh, y_mesh)
xx_2, yy_2 = np.meshgrid(x_mesh_2, y_mesh_2)

z_fit = a0 + a1*yy + a2*xx + a3*yy**2 + a4*xx**2  + a5*xx*yy
z_fit_2 = a0_s2 + a1_s2*yy_2 + a2_s2*xx_2 + a3_s2*yy_2**2 + a4_s2*xx_2**2  + a5_s2*xx_2*yy_2


# set "fig" and "ax" varaibles
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# Plot the original function
ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, z_fit, color='y', alpha=0.5)
ax.plot_surface(xx_2, yy_2, z_fit_2, color='g', alpha=0.5)

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('\nz', linespacing=3)

plt.show()
```

**EDIT**

As **@Alex** pointed out, 2 solutions are obtained, i.e., the two surfaces intersect defining 2 curves:

[image]

If you run the below code, these are obtained in `sol`:

`sol = sym.solve(z_I(x,y) - z_II(x,y), y)`

Now, if we plot these two curves (all of this is in the code below), we find these two branches:

[image]

I realised that this is true in a situation where one surface, i.e, the green one, lies on top of the red-yellow one for a domain of `x` and `y`:

[image]

I would like to find the intersection between these two branches (blue and orange in the 2D plot).

According to what has been discussed, this can be done by `sym.solve` too:

`cross = sym.solve(y_sol_z_I_sym(x) - y_sol_z_II_sym(x), x)`

However, this statement does not work with `sym.sqrt` (it should, since the square root is treated as symbolic...)

Do you know where is the problem?

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



a0 =  -941.487789748
a1 =  0.014688246093
a2 =  -2.53546607894e-05
a3 =  -9.6435353414e-05
a4 =  -2.47408356408e-08
a5 =  3.77057147803e-07

a0_s2 =  -941.483110904
a1_s2 =  0.01381970471
a2_s2 =  -2.63051565187e-05
a3_s2 =  -5.5529184524e-05
a4_s2 =  -2.46707082089e-08
a5_s2 =  3.50929634874e-07

x, y = sym.symbols('x y', real=True)


def z_I(x,y):
        return   a0 + a1*y + a2*x + a3*y**2 + a4*x**2  + a5*x*y

def z_II(x,y):
        return   a0_s2 + a1_s2*y + a2_s2*x + a3_s2*y**2 + a4_s2*x**2  + a5_s2*x*y

sol = sym.solve(z_I(x,y) - z_II(x,y), y)
print 'sol =', sol

# For obtaining the plot of the two branches y=y(x), we need np.sqrt
def y_sol_z_I(x):
    return 0.000319359080035813*x - 1.22230952828787e-15*np.sqrt(-1.07919313606384e+24*x**2 + 2.00910207755286e+28*x - 1.12101975048632e+30) + 10.6162640815323


def y_sol_z_II(x):
   return 0.000319359080035813*x + 1.22230952828787e-15*np.sqrt(-1.07919313606384e+24*x**2 + 2.00910207755286e+28*x - 1.12101975048632e+30) + 10.6162640815323

# For obtaining where the two branches y=y(x) intersect, we need sym.sqrt
def y_sol_z_I_sym(x):
    return 0.000319359080035813*x - 1.22230952828787e-15*sym.sqrt(-1.07919313606384e+24*x**2 + 2.00910207755286e+28*x - 1.12101975048632e+30) + 10.6162640815323


def y_sol_z_II_sym(x):
   return 0.000319359080035813*x + 1.22230952828787e-15*sym.sqrt(-1.07919313606384e+24*x**2 + 2.00910207755286e+28*x - 1.12101975048632e+30) + 10.6162640815323


cross = sym.solve(y_sol_z_I_sym(x) - y_sol_z_II_sym(x), x)
print ' cross = ', cross


##### Plotting:
# set "fig" and "ax" varaibles
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# Plot the original function:
x_mesh = np.linspace(10.0000000000000, 2000.0000000000000, 20)
x_mesh_2 = np.linspace(10.0000000000000, 2000.0000000000000, 20)
print x_mesh[0]
print x_mesh[-1]
y_mesh = np.linspace(-4.4121040129800, 10.8555489379000, 20)
y_mesh_2 = np.linspace(8.0622039627300, 17.6458151433000, 20)
print y_mesh[0]
print y_mesh[-1]

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x_mesh, y_mesh)
xx_2, yy_2 = np.meshgrid(x_mesh_2, y_mesh_2)

ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, z_I(xx ,yy), color='y', alpha=0.5)
ax.plot_surface(xx_2, yy_2, z_II(xx_2, yy_2), color='g', alpha=0.5)

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('\n z, linespacing=3')

# New figure for the y=y(x) function:
fig = plt.figure()
x = np.linspace(10.0, 2000.0, 10000)
plt.plot(x, y_sol_z_I(x))
plt.plot(x, y_sol_z_II(x))
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Exact expression of y=y(x)\nas a result of making $z^{I}(x,y)=z^{II}(x,y)$')
tics_shown =  [10, 250, 500, 750, 1000, 1250, 1500, 1750, 2000, 2250]
plt.xticks(tics_shown)
plt.grid()


# New figure for the y=y(x) function in circle:
fig = plt.figure()
x_circle = np.linspace(10.0, 2000.0*100, 10000*100)
plt.plot(x_circle, y_sol_z_I(x_circle))
plt.plot(x_circle, y_sol_z_II(x_circle))
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Exact expression of y=y(x)\nas a result of making $z^{I}(x,y)=z^{II}(x,y)$')
plt.grid()


plt.show()
```

Comment: "How could I find the equation y=y(x) for this intersection?" - You need to solve the quadratic equation given by `z_I(x, y) = z_II(x, y)`.

Comment: Are you asking a maths question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are looking for a *symbolic* solution (as opposed to numeric), you need a library for symbolic manipulation, such as SymPy.

```
import sympy as sym
x, y = sym.symbols('x y', real=True)
z_I = a0 + a1*y + a2*x + a3*y**2 + a4*x**2  + a5*x*y
z_II = a0_s2 + a1_s2*y + a2_s2*x + a3_s2*y**2 + a4_s2*x**2  + a5_s2*x*y
sol = sym.solve(z_I-z_II, y)
```

The array `sol`  contains two solutions, which is not unusual for quadratic equations.

```
[0.000319359080035813*x - 1.22230952828787e-15*sqrt(-1.07919313606384e+24*x**2 + 2.00910207755286e+28*x - 1.12101975048632e+30) + 10.6162640815323, 
 0.000319359080035813*x + 1.22230952828787e-15*sqrt(-1.07919313606384e+24*x**2 + 2.00910207755286e+28*x - 1.12101975048632e+30) + 10.6162640815323]
```

If you want to find where they meet, use

```
cross = sym.solve(sol[0]-sol[1])
```

which returns `[55.9652951064934, 18560.7401898885]`, the x-coordinates of the intersection points.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have been thinking quite a lot on the two solutions and arrived to a conclusion. Please see above edit. Thanks again

Comment: You were trying to equate Python functions (as if using a numerical solver from SciPy) instead of SymPy expressions. See the updated answer.

Comment: `sym.solve(sol[0]-sol[1])` returns the error `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object` Thanks

Comment: Not for me in sympy 1.1.  Try this without all the extra baggage, just the code in my answer plus the definitions of constants from your post. You have some redundant import statements in your code.

Comment: By running your code and upgrading to sympy 1.1, [this example](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/sympy.html#equation-solving) shows that it is possible to know the `x` and `y` coordinates of intersection. Therefore, `cross = sym.solve([sol[0]-y, sol[1]-y], [x,y])` should return both coordinates. However, it returns an empty list, `cross  = []` Do you know why this is happening? Thanks for your help

Comment: I guess it is because algebra doesn't work exactly like we expect when floating point numbers are involved.

Comment: you're right, but consider this case: A parabola in U: `def g(x): return x**2`. An inverted parabola: `def h(x): return -x**2 + 100`. Both intersect in 2 points, say `(x1, y1)` and `(x2,y2)` .

Comment: _Contd.-_ If we now say `cross = sym.solve([h(x)-y, g(x)-y], [x,y])`,  magically ( :) ) it happens that `cross` gives us those  `(x1, y1)` and `(x2,y2)` -> `cross = [(-5*sqrt(2), 50), (5*sqrt(2), 50)]`  Now, the very interesting thing is what the _hell_ makes the difference between `sol[0]-y`  and `h(x)-y` so that  `sym.solve([sol[0]-y, sol[1]-y], [x,y])` does not work and `sym.solve([h(x)-y, g(x)-y], [x,y])`  does work! This is a mystery :(

Comment: My last comment here. 100 is an integer, precisely represented as such in SymPy. Your example had floating number points with many digits. Also, you continue sticking Python functions where they do not belong. Please read [SymPy tutorial](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/). If you still have questions, post a new question.